# Meaning of non-community wiki answers?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, community-wiki

The badges section mentions that when someone earns ''at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers'' in a specific tag, he/she gets a bronze badge for that tag.

However, the meaning of this string ''non-community wiki answers'' is not elaborated here. Maybe it could be edited, or one can add a link if that info is hosted elsewhere, but what exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certain posts are marked as *community wiki*, for a variety of reasons. Essentially, if you mark one of your answers as community wiki, it is very easy for other users to edit your post and contribute content to it, and it is taken as an encouragement on others to do so. Because of this, certain 'benefits', including reputation, are suspended in community wiki posts.

For more information, see [the help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) or [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) at Meta Stack Exchange. It is my understanding that most people feel this information is visible enough and does not need further highlighting - it is only one search query away at the help center.

Comment: Thanks. But this link that you posted could be put over there as well, that's what I meant. :)